# string get single / multiple values

Tags: string, powershell

I have a string

```
<P><A href="http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=39d8f0cd-4043-4eed-bd27-2f26748da664">Microsoft Word 2003 Service Pack 3</A> <BR>(2863866)</P>`
```

from which I need to get out 3 values:

```
- $value1 = characters between " "
- $value2 = characters between "> </A  
- $value3 = characters between ( )
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try regex:

```
$string = '<P><A href="http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=39d8f0cd-4043-4eed-bd27-2f26748da664">Microsoft Word 2003 Service Pack 3</A> <BR>(2863866)</P>`'
$regex = '"(.*?)">(.*?)<\/A>.*?\((.*?)\)'

if($string -match $regex) {
    $Matches[1]
    $Matches[2]
    $Matches[3]
}

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=39d8f0cd-4043-4eed-bd27-2f26748da664
Microsoft Word 2003 Service Pack 3
2863866
```

This would require all elements to always be there and in the same order (link, name of link, parantheses)

Comment: this is awesome! If I understand it correctly than it says

    - $value1 = "(.*?)" 
    - $value2 = >(.*?)<
    - finish after < \ and ignore any character starting /A>.*? until \ character (
    - $value3 = ((.*?)\)

do I get it correctly?

Comment: Mostly. You would read it litteraly: `"$value1">$value2</A>dontcarewhatshere($value3)`. The `\ ` are to escape special regex-characters like `/`, `(` and `)` Any whitespace or character out of place would break it atm. so be careful. Regex is cruel that way, so I hope your input data is following standards and are not handwritten by 20 different people, hehe :)

Comment: heh with Microsoft one newer really know :D thanks for solution, explanation and warning

Comment: Frode please I moved FW with my project solving one interesting join which give me new string. Everything works fine with your previews solution, but I need to get $matches[4] and have no idea how to do that. could U take a look pls  
STRING:  
    `@{innerHTML=<P><A href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=522536">MS15-001</A> </P>} @{innerHTML=<P><STRONG>Vulnerability in Windows Application Compatibility Cache Coul
d Allow Elevation of Privilege (3023266) `  
and I want to get
<STRONG>(.*?)</STRONG>    
any idea how the regex '"(.*?)">(.*?)<\/A>.*?\((.*?)\)' should be updated?

Comment: The sample is missing `</STRONG>`. I suggest you read and practice on regex so you could fix it yourself. Checkout https://www.regex101.com/r/sA4aA2/1 . They explain the characters in the regex language and lets you test your regex against your sample text.